# $X$ is a random variable with PDF $f$, with $f$ continuous at $x=a$. Then $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^-}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}P(X\in(a,a+\varepsilon))=f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, solution-verification

**The Problem:** Let $X$ be a random variable with density function $f$, and assume that $f$ is continuous at $x=a$. Prove that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}P(X\in(a,a+\varepsilon))=f(a).$$
**My Attempt:** Let $\eta>0$ be given. Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, it also right-continuous at $a$. Therefore, we can choose a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<\varepsilon<\delta$ then $\vert f(a+\varepsilon)-f(a)\vert<\eta.$ This also implies that if $0<x-a<\delta$ then $\vert f(x)-f(a)\vert<\eta.$ It follows that if $0<\varepsilon<\eta$, then
\begin{align}
\left\vert\frac{1}{\varepsilon}P(X\in(a,a+\varepsilon))-f(a)\right\vert&=\left\vert\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_a^{a+\varepsilon}[f(x)-f(a)\,dx\right\vert\\
&\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_a^{a+\varepsilon}\vert f(x)-f(a)\vert\,dx\\
&<\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_a^{a+\varepsilon}\eta\,dx\\
&=\eta.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon}P(X\in(a,a+\varepsilon))=f(a).$$

---

Do you agree with my approach and execution above?
Thank you very much for your time and appreciate any and all feedback.

Comment: I think it should be written as: $\cdots$ This also implies that if $0<x-a<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\eta$. It follows that if $0<\epsilon<\delta$., then $\cdots$. You also missed the right bracket after the first equality sign.

Comment: Yo proof seems correct to me.

Comment: @torontohrb you are absolutely right, thank you for your feedback :-)